# What are the required steps in setting up and customizing IziToast.js and IziModal,js

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I'm setting up and customizing the `IziToast.js` and `IziModal.js` in my web application through the header and footer of the main blade but doesnt seem to work at all.

```
<script>
    iziToast.settings({
        timeout: 10000,
        resetOnHover: true,
        icon: 'material-icons',
        transitionIn: 'flipInX',
        transitionOut: 'flipOutX',
        onOpening: function(){
            console.log('callback abriu!');
        },
        onClosing: function(){
            console.log("callback fechou!");
        }
    });
  </script>
```

I expect the step by step installation of the latest `IziToast.js` plugin in both boostrap and javascript